# Embedding Fonts in PDF from LaTeX Source with pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdflatex

I need to embed the fonts that I'm using in my TeX document in my output PDF.  I'm using pdflatex for TeX processing, and TextMate as my editor.

I can't find any reference on how to embed the fonts I need in the PDF document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the pdfTex documentation,

> ## 5 Setting up fonts
>
> pdfTEX can work with Type 1 and TrueType fonts (and to some extent also
>   with OpenType fonts). Font les should be available and embedded for all
>   fonts used in the document. It is possible to use METAFONT-- generated
>   fonts in pdfTEX  but it is strongly recommended not to use these fonts
>   if an equivalent is available in Type 1 or TrueType format, if only
>   because bitmap Type 3 fonts render very poorly in (older versions of)
>   Adobe Reader. Given the free availability of Type 1 versions of all the
>   Computer Modern fonts, and the ability to use standard PostScript fonts,
>   there is rarely a need to use bitmap fonts in pdfTEX.

You probably need to either install the Type 1 Computer Modern fonts. Modern tex-live has them. If you have an older TeX distro, there is `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

Hello, world.

\end{document}
```

Now, if you check the fonts in the resulting document with, e.g., `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
SZVHEC+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
```

Bingo. Embedded type 1 font.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following line in your mypaper.tex file:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Compile to pdf after using latex:

```
dvipdfm -p letter mypaper
```

I checked using pdffonts, no more T3 fonts. Bingo.

Comment: I don't know, I was not concerned with this problem.