# Embeding fonts to PDF

Tags: pdf, postscript

I know many people that face the problem of "A PDF font is not embedded." when submitting papers to IEEE/ACM etc.

This error occurs when a PDF document does not include all the fonts that it references. This may cause fonts to be substituted when printing or rendering, yielding papers that have incorrect spacing or equations.

The solution to this problem is:
ps2pdf -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dEPSCrop=true -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress '%S.ps' '%.pdf'

If you are using the new 'ps2pdf13' you can substitute the 'ps2pdf'.

If you do not have the .dvi to create the .ps, then convert the .pdf to .ps, with pdf2ps.

--
You can also try using Adobe Acrobat Professional: Advanced->PDF Optimizer...->Fonts
Then choose to embed the fonts.

--
Another solution: pdftexDownloadBase14 settings in the updmap.cfg file is set to true to make pdflatex to embed the base 14 pdf fonts. If you use normal latex then you should set dvipdfmDownloadBase14 to true

In Linux: updmap --edit

--
If somebody knows another way please answer to this post....

Comment: if you have a solution, *please* put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you still generate PostScript. Use pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX and generate the PDF directly. Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for TeX-related questions.

Comment: I am not sure if these would embed the fonts by default. The proposed link is actually good source of information

Comment: @ipapapa: At least you control font embedding easily with pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

In short, from [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18570151/1287856), include the following line in your `mypaper.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Compile to pdf after using latex:

```
dvipdfm -p letter mypaper
```

I checked using pdffonts, no more T3 fonts. Bingo.